# Manual Color and Fill with mixed line/point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to emulate the line/point style on this single variable graph(image 1) on a graph that has two variables. The closest I can get is in the second image

[Single variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggzBl.png)

[Multi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02tPh.png)

Here is the code I am using for the multiline graph.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

national_employment <- read.csv("Data/Tab/National/emplyment.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(total_pop = total_pop * 1000,
         labor_force = labor_force * 1000,
         employed = employed * 1000,
         unemployed = unemployed * 1000,
         unemployed_rate = round(unemployed / labor_force, 4))

# Employement and Labor force visualizations
group_colors <- c('employed' = "#1076bc",
                  'labor_force' = '#939598')
group_labels <- c('employed' = 'Total Employed',
                  'labor_force' = 'Total Labor Force')
national_employment %>% 
  gather(employed, labor_force, key = type, value = total) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, total, color = type)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size = 2.5, stroke = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Total",
       title = "U.S. National Employement",
       subtitle = "2017 statistics reflect August 2017 data",
       caption = "Source: U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2000, 2020, by = 5), limits = c(2000, 2020)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), labels = comma, breaks = seq(100000000, 164000000, by = 10000000), 
                     limits = c(100000000, 161000000)) +
  scale_color_manual('Legend', values = group_colors, labels = group_labels) +
  theme_hc() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 9.5, color = '#929598'),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = '#bcbec0',size = 1.5,lineend = 'butt'),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color = '#bcbec0',size = 1.5,lineend = 'butt'),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = -.12, color = '#bcbec0'),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#d1d3d4", size = 0.5))
```

How can I set the scale color/fill correctly to emulate the first graph?

Answer (score 1):

Simple and dummy solution, but works - make points with thick borders (same color as background):

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 10), y = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line(size = 2, color = "#34B2EF") +
    geom_point(size = 3, fill = "#34B2EF", color = "white", shape = 21, stroke = 2) +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: How would you apply that when you need two lines/points that represent different variables and need to be different color?  Thats where i am running into the issue. A single line/point graph I'm doing fine making

Comment: You'd copy your current `group_colors` into `group_fill`, add `scale_fill_manual`, and set the `color` in the `geom_point` to "white" as in @PoGibas's answer.  You'll also have to set `fill = type` in your `geom_point`.

Comment: @JakeKaupp This was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!